# Saving/reading large xml string to/from file

Tags: android, xml, file, save

So, my app receives a large xml from a soap server. I wish to save this in a file, for later use. I managed to do this, and to read the file. BUT the result (after reading) is a garbled xml! A large portion of text (412 characters) from the latter part of the xml is copied and pasted at the end of my xml, and I can't figure out why this is happening.
 I have tried 2 ways to write the file and 2 ways to read the file, no dice! (will post code below) Note: xml is large 5000-20000 characters, so I used methods to keep eclipse from returning out of memory error.

BOTTOM LINE:

-input xml file is correct

-output xml file is incorrect

-tried 2 save methods

-tried 2 read methods

-wtf?!

save code 1:

```
                    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(string.getBytes());

                    FileOutputStream fos = ctx.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

                        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                        int length;
                        while ((length = is.read(buffer))>0){
                            fos.write(buffer, 0, length);
                        }

                        fos.flush();
                        fos.close();
                        is.close();
```

save code 2 :

```
                InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(string.getBytes());

                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                            is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                    FileOutputStream fos = ctx.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String line = null;

                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        Log.e("stuff is good", "line: "+line);
                        sb.append(line);

                        if (sb.toString().length() > 10000) {
                           fos.write(sb.toString().getBytes());
                           fos.flush();
                           sb = new StringBuilder();

                        }

                    }

                    fos.write(sb.toString().getBytes());
                    fos.flush();
                    is.close();
                    fos.close();
```

read code 1:

```
            FileInputStream fis = openFileInput("caca");
                    int c;
                    StringBuilder fileContent = new StringBuilder();

                    while((c=fis.read())!=-1)
                            {
                        fileContent.append((char)c);

                            }
                    fis.close();

                    Log.e("TEST TEST", "XML length = "
                            +String.valueOf(fileContent.length()) );
                    Log.e("TEST TEST", "XML = "
                            +fileContent );
```

read code 2 :

```
        FileInputStream fis;
                    fis = openFileInput("caca");
                    StringBuffer fileContent = new StringBuffer("");
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    int i =1;
                    while (fis.read(buffer) != -1) {
                        fileContent.append(new String(buffer));
                        Log.v("TEST"+ String.valueOf(i), new String(buffer) );
                        i++;
                    }
                    Log.e("TEST TEST", "XML length = "
                            +String.valueOf(fileContent.length()) );
                    Log.e("TEST TEST", "XML = "
                            +fileContent );
```

save to file code :

```
                        File myFile = new File("/sdcard/mysdfile.txt");
                        myFile.createNewFile();
                        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
                        OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = 
                                                new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
                        myOutWriter.append(fileContent);
                        myOutWriter.close();
                        fOut.close();
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                                "Done writing SD 'mysdfile.txt'",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Sorry for the long post, but after 3 days, I'm at my wits end. Any input would be nice, thank you!

Comment: Sorry, 323go, that one got away from me. I deleted the other 6 or 7 inappropriate Log.e ' s before I posted the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok.... I fixed it , I have no idea why it works.

save code:

```
    public static void Save(String filename, String string, 
          Context ctx) {
            Log.e("stuff is good", "xml length b4 save= "+String.valueOf(string.length()));

                try {
                    FileOutputStream fOut = ctx.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 

                    OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = 
                                            new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
                    myOutWriter.append(Login.messagesXmlDump);
                    myOutWriter.close();
                    fOut.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
```

read code:

```
                    Save("LOL", messagesXmlDump, getApplicationContext());

                try {

                    FileInputStream fis = openFileInput("LOL");
                    int c;
                    StringBuilder fileContent = new StringBuilder();

                    while((c=fis.read())!=-1)
                            {
                        fileContent.append((char)c);

                            }
                    fis.close();
```

Managed to write/read a 70k characters long xml. Maybe that recursive method of saving it wasn't the best idea. Think I over-complicated a simple matter.

Sorry for wasting your time :(

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html) for this:

```
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url + id);

try {
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
    InputStream content = response.getEntity().getContent();        
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    IOUtils.copy(content, writer, "utf-8");
    return writer.toString(); 

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    Log.e(tag, "client problem:" + e.getMessage());
    throw new RuntimeException("client problem",e);
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(tag, "IO problem:" + e.getMessage());
    throw new RuntimeException("IO problem",e);
}
```

Then just write out the string as usual.

Comment: ok, I'm confused. How is this supposed to help me? I already have the string I want to write, the problem occurs when I write the string to a file and then read it again.